# How to change font for right-to-left language in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, right-to-left

I am developing a WordPress website which has posts in both English (left-to-right, ltr) and Urdu (right-to-left, rtl) Languages. I paste the post data in wp editor and it gets published fine.

I want a specific Urdu language font (named Mehr Nastaliq) to be applied on my posts in Urdu language while I want theme default fonts to be applied on posts in English language. Please guide me how I can do that.

Very thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Assign a unique CSS class name to elements that will contain Urdu text.

```
.urdu {
  direction: rtl;
}
```